# Не отображается стрелочка slisk-slider

Tags: javascript, css

Всeм пpивет, пишу свой мини блог, подключил `slick-slider`, и у меня не отображается левая стрелочка на слайдере, с правой почему то всё в порядке.

```js
$('.top-posts__wrapper').slick({
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><img src="img/arrow-left.svg"></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><img src="img/arrow-right.svg"></button>'
});
```

```css
.slick-prev {
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #520f0f;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: 25px;
}

.slick-next {
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #520f0f;
    border-radius: 100%;
    right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
    <section class="top-posts">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="top-posts__title">Лучшие посты</h2>
            <div class="top-posts__wrapper">
                <div class="top-posts__post">
                    <img class="top-posts__post-img" src="img/1-Blog-1.jpg" alt="">
                    <h3 class="top-posts__post-title">Первый пост</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="top-posts__post">
                    <img class="top-posts__post-img" src="img/690x380_0x0a330c2a_14263452901600432118.jpeg"
                        alt="">
                    <h3 class="top-posts__post-title">Второй пост</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="top-posts__post">
                    <img class="top-posts__post-img" src="img/Без названия.jpeg" alt="">
                    <h3 class="top-posts__post-title">Третий пост</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста минимальный рабочий `html` код, чтобы можно было бы у себя протестировать весь ваш код.

Comment: ```Есть, сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Левая стрелка скорее всего находится под слайдом. Попробуйте добавить в стили:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Это должно помочь.
Если не поможет попробуйте для проверки увеличить, скажем до 10000.

Comment: Странно, почему же некст стрелка не была под слайдом))) Спасибо!

Comment: Если помогло - не забудьте отметить решением.

Comment: @Андрей Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour